# How join multiple tables, making sure to expand the smaller table to the bigger

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a series of database tables that need to be joined together starting from a top and reducing the number of points selected from the tables.  But at the last step, I need to expand a last table to meet the number of points in the big table.  Here is the example

analytes

Analyte_Index, Analyte_Name ...
     1          , 'dCMP'

analytefolders

```
Analyte_Index , Folder_Index ...
 1            ,  1
```

folders

```
Folder_Index, Folder_Path ...
 1          , 'c:\temp'
```

files

```
File_Index, Folder_Index, File_Name ...
1         ,  1          , 'test.dat'
```

peaks

```
Peak_Index, File_Index, Folder_Index, Cluster_Index ...
1         , 1         , 1           , 1
2         , 1         , 1           , 1
3         , 1         , 1           , 2
4         , 1         , 1           , 3
5         , 1         , 1           , 3
6         , 1         , 1           , 4
```

clusters

```
Cluster_Index ...
1
2
3
```

The peaks table has the big chunk of table, and a cluster can have many peaks within.  So all the other table reduce the number of points that are selected from the peaks table, and this works quite well.  After the select, there is ~9,000,000 points, if I do not include the join on the clusters.

Here is my query

```
select  peaks.Peak_Index, peaks.Cluster_Index, peaks.P_maxAmplitude, peaks.P_averageAmplitude, clusters.C_averageAmplitude
from peaks
join files
  on files.File_Index = peaks.File_Index
join folders
  on folders.Folder_Index = files.Folder_Index
join analytefolders
  on analytefolders.Folder_Index = folders.Folder_Index
join analytes
  on analytes.Analyte_Index = analytefolders.Analyte_Index
join clusters
  on clusters.Cluster_Index=peaks.Peak_Index

where analytes.Analyte_Name='dCMP'
```

With the join on clusters, the number of rows returns is reduced to ~1,000,000 (the number of clusters).  What I need to to have the data from the clusters expanded to match the number of peaks.  I have tried all the joins that I can think of and changed the order of the joins, but this is beyond my limited SQL skill.

Comment: I think your last join should be `on clusters.Cluster_Index=peaks.Cluster_Index`

Comment: Oh, my head.  I just spent 2 hours trying different joins to get this to work and that was all that was wrong!   Thank you.

Comment: OK, I added that as the answer, can you accept it so folks know the question is resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last join should be `on clusters.Cluster_Index=peaks.Cluster_Index`